# How to have different themes for notebooks and python scripts in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vs-color-theme-editor

I'm using visual studio code and would like to have different color themes for my notebooks (white) vs my .py files (dark). How can I do this? I already checked the "Ignore Vscode Theme" box in the settings, but still can't find an option to just change the jupyter notebook theme alone. I'm using the regular Jupyter extension.

Comment: I am afraid It's impossible.

Comment: I'm surprised that this is not a common thing @Steven-MSFT